# How to send parameters between ViewModel and ViewRepository

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to send params from my ViewModel to my ViewRepository but I don't understan how can I send some params.

For example this is my observer in my fragment:

```
apoyaLoginViewModel.getPostLoginApoya(tokenApoya, usuario, password).observe(getActivity(), new Observer<PostLoginApoya>() {
          @Override
          public void onChanged(PostLoginApoya postLoginApoya) {
                loginApoyaModel = postLoginApoya;
          }
});
```

I'm sending some params in this line:

```
getPostLoginApoya(tokenApoya, usuario, password)
```

And this is my ViewModel:

```
public class ApoyaLoginViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private ApoyaLoginViewRepositori apoyaLoginViewRepositori;
    private LiveData<PostLoginApoya> postLoginApoya;

    public ApoyaLoginViewModel(Application aplication){
        super(aplication);
        apoyaLoginViewRepositori = new ApoyaLoginViewRepositori();
        postLoginApoya = apoyaLoginViewRepositori.loginApoyaUser;

    }

    public LiveData<PostLoginApoya> getPostLoginApoya(String tokenApoya, String usuario, String password){return postLoginApoya;}

}
```

And this is a fragment of my ViewRepository:

```
ApoyaLoginViewRepositori(){

        seccion15ServerClient = Seccion15ServerClient.getInstance();
        seccionApiService = seccion15ServerClient.getSeccionApiService();
        loginApoyaUser = getLoginUser();

    }

    public MutableLiveData<PostLoginApoya> getLoginUser(String tokenApoya, String usuario, String password){

        if(loginApoyaUser == null){
            loginApoyaUser = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }
```

But I'm getting an error in this line:

```
loginApoyaUser = getLoginUser();
```

This is because my method getLoginUser has 3 parameters but my constructor no. maybe this is not the correct way to send information between ViewModel and ViewRepository.

How can I send this params to my constructor in my ViewRepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass any argument in `getPostLoginApoya`, create a separate method for that: `loginApoyaUser(token, usuario, password)`. and call this method whenever you want to login the user, you will automatically receive an event with the logged in user.

fragment:

```
viewModel.getPostLoginApoya().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<PostLoginApoya>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(PostLoginApoya postLoginApoya) {
    // do something with your user here
    }
});

//you have to call this method somewhere, when you click on a button for example.
viewModel.loginApoyaUser(token, usuario, password);
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ApoyaLoginViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private ApoyaLoginViewRepositori apoyaLoginViewRepositori;
    private LiveData<PostLoginApoya> postLoginApoya;

    public ApoyaLoginViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        apoyaLoginViewRepositori = new ApoyaLoginViewRepositori();
        postLoginApoya = apoyaLoginViewRepositori.getPostLoginApoya();
    }


    public LiveData<PostLoginApoya> getPostLoginApoya(){
        return postLoginApoya;
    }


    public void loginApoyaUser(String tokenApoya, String usuario, String password) {
        apoyaLoginViewRepositori.loginApoyaUser(tokenApoya, usuario, password);
    }

}
```

Repo:

```
public class ApoyaLoginViewRepositori {

    private MutableLiveData<PostLoginApoya> postLoginApoyaLiveData;
    private PostLoginApoya postLoginApoya;

    public ApoyaLoginViewRepositori() {
        postLoginApoyaLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public LiveData<PostLoginApoya> getPostLoginApoya() {
        return postLoginApoyaLiveData;
    }

    public void loginApoyaUser(String tokenApoya, String usuario, String password) {
        postLoginApoya =  //login user here

        //notify observers data has been changed
        postLoginApoyaLiveData.postValue(postLoginApoya);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, this solution works!! I didn't remember how pass parameters between fragments, viewmodel and repository.